# Compass north and south are reversed on my Samsung Galaxy 2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, compass

Since upgrading my phone to ICS, my compass is reversed, with the north end pointing south.

I have tried waving the phone in a figure 8 pattern and flipping it over on all axis.

What can I do to get my compass pointing the right way?

Comment: Have you tried using different compass apps, to see if it's the app or your phone/OS that has the problem? It's possible the app you're using may have problems with the compass in ICS.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I've tried a variety of apps, and as far as I can tell, they all show the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on [this page](http://www.japanmobiletech.com/2012/04/installing-ics-cyanogenmod-9-on-your-sc.html), and the solution was to download and install a [compass fix patch](https://www.box.com/s/7d803a7eba81f6478325).